# Get file size of attempted upload when UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE error occurs?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there any way to get file size of attempted upload when you get `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`? That is when file being uploaded exceeded `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

Comment: It stops processing the upload when the limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']. It has some overhead and represents the total size of a POST request, but in some situations this will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There´s no way to control PHP core behavior. When a upload fail, the temporary file is deleted, and the array returns an error, without the file size:

```
Array
(
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => SManager.chm
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

When you go back to move_uploaded_file() or copy(), we dont have the temp file and any other information besides the error, and the name of the origin file.

You can always grab PHP source code, modify it, compile and have this values returned. But, not as a standard.